# Error while installing Tomcat in CentOS

Tags: java, installation, centos, tomcat7

I tried to install a Tomcat servlet container in my CentOS machine and I'm getting some errors.

I succeeded doing

```
tar -zxvf apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz
```

But I failed executing:

```
 [root@localhost mpatil]# mv apache-tomcat-7.0.47 uportal-tomcat
 [root@localhost mpatil]# export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/java
 [root@localhost mpatil]# export TOMCAT_HOME=/path/to/your/tomcat
 [root@localhost mpatil]# $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh
 bash: /path/to/your/tomcat/bin/startup.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you actually export the paths you wrote in your post? These are just example paths and unless you created these directories and put your java/tomcat there they won't work.

Comment: u means where the jdk and tomcat files is there that path will provide?

Comment: Yes. it should probably be something like
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk
export TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/uportal_tomcat

all depends where you extracted/installed your JDK and Tomcat

Comment: [pretty good guide here](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos)

Comment: MY JDK in  `/home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz` i tried `export JAVA_HOME=/home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz` nothing will comming. why?

Comment: i tried what u told that link but am getting errors like what i mentioned.Can you clarify my doubts pls

Comment: jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz - you need to extract the jdk first as you did with tomcat. Just follow the guide I posted and you should be all good...

Comment: how to extract the jdk ?

Comment: yes, that should work. then export the JAVA_HOME variable with the directory where java got extracted (probably /home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64). But it's best practice to keep your jdk and tomcat in /opt or /usr folders. if it's in your home folder other users won't be able to use it without special permissions

Comment: `[root@localhost mpatil]# tar -xzf jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz 
tar (child): jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`
 i tried above mentioned but am getting error

Comment: are you in the correct folder (where your jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz is)?

Comment: ya `[root@localhost mpatil]#  find /home -type f -name  jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
/home/mpatil/softwares/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz`

Comment: cd /home/mpatil/softwares/ and then

tar -xzf jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: `[root@localhost mpatil]# cd /home/mpatil/softwares/
[root@localhost softwares]#  tar -xzf jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
[root@localhost softwares]# ` (i already installed this back 2 months back)

Comment: what happens if you try to run java -version ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40740/discussion-between-ram-and-ciny)